# Open xls and xlsx with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls, xlsx

I want to open my excel file with Apache POI.

I don’t know if a file is xls or xlsx. I have only something like this:

```
InputStream myExcelFile = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getData());
```

This way I can open xls file:

```
HSSFWorkbook hsf = new HSSFWorkbook(myxls);
```

And this way I can open xlsx file:

```
XSSFWorkbook xsf = new XSSFWorkbook(myxls);
```

How can I open both types of files if I don’t know format?

Comment: Try using either the extension of the file, or if that is not sufficient then determine based on the MIME type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the work:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(myExcelFile);
```

Then you can check the exact type created by the factory:

```
if (wb instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
    // do whatever
} else if (wb instanceof SXSSFWorkbook) {
    // do whatever
} else if (wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Anyway if you want to know the real type of the file before using it you can use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/).

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067983/apache-poi-3-9-workbookfactory-method-not-found)

Answer (score 6):

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(myExcelFile);
if (wb instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
    // do whatever
} else if (wb instanceof SXSSFWorkbook) {
    // do whatever
} else if (wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
    // do whatever
}
```

The aforementioned approach will work.

But incase you are dealing with large files, there is a possibility that you will get `File` as `ByteArayInputStream`. In this case, the bellow approach shall work.

```
ByteArayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getData());

if(bais != null && POIFSFileSystem.hasPOIFSHeader(bais)) {
    System.out.println(".xls extention excel file");
    //do whatever
}
else if(bais != null && POIXMLDocument.hasOOXMLHeader(bais)) {
    System.out.println(".xlsx extention excel file");
    //do whatever
}
else {
    //wrong file format. throw exception.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can let POI do the job for you, by using `WorkbookFactory` to automatically have the file extension detected opened for you.

```
Workbook w = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("hello.xls"));
```

Of course, you can use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to detect the file format for you!

Answer (score 1):

I woul recommend to use this FilenameUtils.getExtension from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29)
:

String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension("path to the file");